# How to unmap observable arrays

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a complex view model which contains several collections. Users can add new items to the collections. I manually create the view model and use `ko.mapping.fromJS` to bind the data from the server. The collections can be empty or already contain values.

I search for a way to create JSON from the view data to send it back to server.

When I use `ko.mapping` then the JSON contains only empty objects for the added items because they didn't exist in the initial data.

When I use `ko.toJSON` then the JSON contains the ko_mapping property.

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/delixfe/qEdnf/19/).

One solution seems to be to use `ko.toJSON` and to remove the ko_mapping property, but I was hoping that there is a better solution.

The code:

```
var initialData = {
   title: 'numbers:',
   numbers: []
   };

function Data() {
    var self = this;

    self.title = ko.observable();  
    self.numbers = ko.observableArray();

    self.addNumber = function() {
        self.numbers.push({
            id: ko.observable(2)
        });
    };

    self.removeNumber = function(item) {
        self.numbers.destroy(item);
    };
}

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.masterData = [{
        id: 1,
        caption: "One"},
    {
        id: 2,
        caption: "Two"}];

    self.data = new Data();

    self.toMappedJSON = function() {
        var json = ko.mapping.toJSON(self.data);
        $('#json').text(js_beautify(json));
    };

   self.toJSON = function() {
       var json = ko.toJSON(self.data);
       $('#json').text(js_beautify(json));
   };    
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.mapping.fromJS(initialData, {}, viewModel.data);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);​
```

The html:

```html
<div data-bind="with: data">
<h2 data-bind="text: title"></h2>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: numbers">
        <li>
           <select data-bind="value: id, options: $root.masterData, optionsText: 'caption', optionsValue: 'id'"></select>
            value: <span data-bind="text: id"></span>
            <button data-bind="click: $parent.removeNumber">-</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button data-bind="click: addNumber">+</button>
</div>

<h2>JSON</h2>
<div>
    <button data-bind="click: toMappedJSON">ko.mapping.toJSON</button>
    <button data-bind="click: toJSON">ko.toJSON</button>    
</div>
<textarea id="json" rows="15" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A requirement of the mapping plugin when it comes to unmapping is that all objects must have been created with the plugin. When you add the items to the array you didn't create them with the mapping plugin. Simply change your add method to this.

```
self.addNumber = function() {
   self.numbers.push(ko.mapping.fromJS({
      id: ko.observable(2)
   }));
};
```

And it should work.

Hope this helps.